# Null pointer exception customer adapter

Tags: android-listview, custom-adapter, rss-reader

good morning i tried to parse rss and show the result in custom listview but i had a problem with my custom adapter that i created to show a thumbail image with a textview i get usually null pointer excpetion in every execution in genymotion simulator.
this the code of the three files of code :

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> name; 
    ListView maListRSS;
    Bitmap img;
     ArrayList<News> News_data ;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         maListRSS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         name = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         News_data = new ArrayList<News>();
         AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {

                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("جاري التحميل....");
                    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    mProgressDialog.show();
         }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://ahsaber.org/?feed=rss2");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
             DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder db = null;
            try {
                db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
             NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
             for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                 Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                 Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                 NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                 Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                 nameList = ((Node) nameElement).getChildNodes();

                 NodeList websiteList =fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("link");
                 Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                 websiteList = ((Node) websiteElement).getChildNodes();

                 NodeList descriptionList =fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                 Element descriptionElement = (Element) descriptionList.item(0);
                 descriptionList = ((Node) descriptionElement).getChildNodes();

                 NodeList encodedList =fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("content:encoded");

                 Element EnocodeElement = (Element) encodedList.item(0);
                 encodedList = ((Node) EnocodeElement).getChildNodes();
                int start =EnocodeElement.getTextContent().indexOf("http://ahsaber.org");
                int end =EnocodeElement.getTextContent().indexOf(".jpg");
                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("title", ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    map.put("tel", ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    map.put("des", ((Node) descriptionList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    if (end>start)
                    {
                    map.put("imageURL",EnocodeElement.getTextContent().substring(start,end)+".jpg");
                    System.out.println(EnocodeElement.getTextContent().substring(start,end));
                    try {
                        URL lien = new URL(EnocodeElement.getTextContent().substring(start,end)+".jpg");
                         HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) lien.openConnection();
                        InputStream is = null;
                        is = connection.getInputStream();
                        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 

                        News N=new News(img,((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                        News_data.add(N);
                        name.add(map);
                         } 
                       catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }


             }
            return null;
        }
             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                 NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
                           R.layout.listviewrow, News_data);
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 maListRSS.setAdapter(adapter);      
            }
        };
        task.execute((Void[]) null);

     }  

}
```

this the custom adapter class :

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<News> data =new ArrayList<News>() ;

    public NewsAdapter(Context asyncTask, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<News> news_data) {
        super(asyncTask, layoutResourceId, news_data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = asyncTask;
        for (int i=0;i<news_data.size();i++)
        {
        data.add(news_data.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        NewsHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);         
            holder = new NewsHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.newsimage);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.newstitle);            
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (NewsHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        News N= data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(N.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(N.icon);

        return row;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    static class NewsHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

}
```

the news class :

```
public class News {
    public Bitmap icon;
    public String title;
    public News() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }
    public News(Bitmap icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

so this is the logcat :

```
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.example.albir.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:139)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.example.albir.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 10:02:11.584: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line is the exception on (139)? It seems like the only object you reference in onPostExecute that could be null is maListRSS, if you don't have a id/list in activity_main.xml

Comment: think you so much yes this the pb